# File operation functions return, but are not actually committed when Windows shuts down

Tags: windows, mfc, file-handling, system-shutdown

I am working on an MFC application that can (among other things) be used to shut Windows down. When doing this, Windows of course sends the WM_QUERYENDSESSION and WM_ENDSESSION to all applications, mine included. However, the problem is that my application, as part of some destructors, delete certain files (with CFile::Remove) that have been used during the execution. I have reason to believe that the destructors are called (but that is hard to know for certain) when the application is closed by Windows.

However, when Windows starts back up again, I do occasionally notice that the files that were supposed to be deleted are still present. This does not happen consistently, even when the execution of the program is identical (I have a script for testing this). This leads me to think that one of two things are happening: Either a) the destructors are not consistently being called, or b) the Remove function returns, but the file is not actually deleted before Windows is shut down.

The only work-around I have found so far is that if I get the system to wait with the shutdown for approximately 10 seconds after my program has stopped, then the files will be properly deleted. This leads me to believe that b) may be the case.

I hope someone is able to help me with this problem.

Regards
Mort

Comment: Mort, welcome to Stack Overflow. More progress can be made on recommending a solution when you post your code.In any case, do you have a logging mechanism (or ETW points) to validate that the code paths you think are getting executed actually are?  CFile::Remove just calls DeleteFile and and can throw an exception if it fails. (Go look at the source to see what I mean) Is it possible your program is terminating from an uncaught exception?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First of, I do handle the exception thrown by CFile::Remove, but I have yet to see this actually happening.

Comment: Furthermore, I have added logging. When I compare two otherwise identical executions, one where the files are deleted, and one where they are not, I see that the log file is in the latter case is cut towards the end. Ie. the two log files are identical up to a certain point, after which the log from the instance where the files are not deleted, simply stops (in which case the destructors in the relevant objects are not logged). So I cant know for certain that the destructors are called, or if they are, if the remove functions succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your program returns from `WM_ENDSESSION`, Windows can terminate it at any time:

> If the session is being ended, this parameter is TRUE; [the session can end any time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after all applications have returned from processing this message.

If the session ends quickly, then it may end before your destructors run. You must do all your cleanup *before* returning from `WM_ENDSESSION`, because there is no guarantee that you will get a chance to do it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that some versions of Windows report back that file handling operations have been completed before they actually have. This isn't a problem unless shutdown is triggered as some operations, including file delete will be abandoned.

I would suggest that you cope with this by forcing your code to wait for a confirmed deletion of the files (have a process look for the files and raise an event when they've gone) before calling for system shutdown.

Comment: Sounds weird. You mean, there's a bug in windows, whereas it doesn't flush the file operations on shut down?

Comment: This was what I thought could be the case, and my suspicion is strengthened by the fact that if I hold back on shutting down Windows for a number of seconds (using InitiateSystemShutdownEx with a timeout), the files are always deleted. Reducing this time seems to increase the likelihood that the files are not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If the system is properly shut down (nut went sudden power loss or etc.) then all the cached data is flushed. In particular this includes flushing the global file descriptor table (or whatever it's called in your file system) which should commit the file deletion.

So the problem seems to be that the user-mode code doesn't call `DeleteFile`, or it failes (for whatever reason).
Note that there are several ways the application (process) may exit, whereas not always d'tors are called. There are automatic objects which are destroyed in the context of their callstack, plus there are global/static objects, which are initialized and destroyed by the CRT init/cleanup code.

Below is a short summary of ways to terminate the process, with the consequences:

- All process threads exit conventionally (return from their procedure). The OS terminates the process that has no threads. All the d'tors are executed.
- Some threads either exit via `ExitThread` or killed by `TerminateThread`. The automatic objects of those threads are not d'tructed.
- Process exited by `ExitProcess`. Automatic objects are not destructed, global may be destructed (this happens in the CRT is used in a DLL)
- Process is terminated by `TerminateProcess`. All d'tors are not called.

I suggest you check if the `DeleteFile` (or `CFile::Remove` that wraos it) is called indeed, and check also if it succeeds. For instance you may open the same file twice for whatever reason